# Trying the create a random colour generator in PHP

Tags: php, html, random, generator

```
<?php
$_50Shades = array("#150517", "#250517", "#2B1B17", "#342826");

$randKeys = array_rand($_50Shades, 1);

print_r ("<BODY BGCOLOR=\"$randKeys\">");
?>
```

This is my code i have put together using the php manuals and a tutorial for a random colour generator.
I am a beginner in PHP and programming in general, so i am still trying to get to grips with things.
The result is just a black screen, rather than generating one of the random colour i have entered?

Comment: Look at the HTML source code and see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`array_rand` returns a key, not the actual value. Do something like this.

```
<?php
$_50Shades = array("#150517", "#250517", "#2B1B17", "#342826");

$randKeys = array_rand($_50Shades, 1);

print_r ("<BODY BGCOLOR=\"".$_50Shades[$randKeys]."\">");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_rand` returns the *key* corresponding to the chosen value, not the value.

Try this:

```
$_50Shades = array(.....);
$randcol = $_50Shades[array_rand($_50Shades)];
echo "<body style=\"background-color:".$randcol.";\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_50Shades = array("#150517", "#250517", "#2B1B17", "#342826");
$randKeys = $_50Shades[rand(0,count($_50Shades)-1)];
print_r ("<BODY BGCOLOR=\"$randKeys\">");
```

or if you are insistent on using [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

```
$randKeys = $_50Shades[array_rand($_50Shades)];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a quick reply, could you explain why you made those changes on line 2? I am very curious as this i attempted this just to gain some knowledge? thanks again

Comment: rand will do the same thing, if you are looking to pull in a random number, in your case an index. I'm not sure why i chose `rand` over `array_rand` to be honest.

Comment: array_rand returns the key of the array, you access an element of your array through a key , in this case it could be $_50Shades[0] or [1] or [2] or [3]

Comment: if you only return 1, which is the default, it will return an integer and not an array

Comment: Thank you so much :) that makes sense now, i realise where i went wrong.

Comment: @SamuelCook `array_rand()` will choose a random **key**, not a random number like `rand()` does.

Comment: correct, which is why i put `array_rand` inside of the brackets to achieve the index: `$_50Shades[array_rand($_50Shades)];`

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, it returns an array of keys for the random entries.